# Simulating (lazy) NAND memory on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, simulation, virtual-memory

I'm running a firmware simulation in a DLL which has simulated NAND (256MB or 1GB).  I want to avoid allocating memory for this on the heap and instead allocate using virtual memory.

The memory initially needs to be cleared to 0xFF (like NAND is).  However I don't want to pay for that initialization (nor commit un-accessed pages).  So ideally it should only allocate upon access.  And I do not need to retain the data following exit of the simulation.

Initial ideas are

1. VirtualAlloc.  Not sure but thinking perhaps could use guard page and then trap the exception on first access.  Not sure its ideal that a DLL handles such SEH exceptions?  Or is there a better way?
2. Create a big file that's initialized to 0xFF.  Then map view of file with copy-on-write.
   Anyone know if it is possible to create a file with a callback for providing the initial data?

Think probably 1) the way to go but wondering if that's really the best option.

Edit:
3) I've come up with another method that can avoid exception handler and also avoids creating a huge file:
Create a file that is same size as dwAllocationGranularity (64KiB typically).  Fill with 0xFF.  Then create multiple copy-on-write views of that in contiguous memory using MapViewOfFileEx + FILE_MAP_COPY (after an initial VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree to get a suitable base address that we can hope to allocate juxtapositioned views).  Need to test this a bit more fully - slight concern about potential thread races..  I'm ony actually using a single thread but the CRT does start a few too.
This means that any code that only reads the virtual NAND also does not result in all pages getting committed.

Comment: 1 is really good solution. but even better use `MEM_RESERVED` only allocation, handle exception on access and fill memory with `0xFF`, but you need *VEH* in general, not *SEH*

Comment: yes, 3 also good solution, and here of course no any thread race.  why you decide that this can be and how you see this ? anyway exception will be on first write to page, but will be handled in kernel

Comment: @RmMm - possible race is between the VirtualFree and the multiple MapViewOfFileEx calls.  I initially call VirtualAlloc to get a suitable base address then immediately VirtualFree (otherwise the MapoViewOfFileEx calls fail).  I guess I'll just try it a few times if it fails on any of the file mapping functions.  Other option I guess would be to make sure all other threads are not runnable during this section of code.

Comment: yes, here possible. but this yet initialization phase. however i be select 1 variant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, basically 1 is best solution. only i be do next changes - use [*VEH*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-addvectoredexceptionhandler) instead *SEH* - *SEH* handler will be called only if you access memory inside it, when in case *VEH* - access can be ai any context and thread.  and instead use guard page, i be initial only reserve region of memory without real allocation. so any access to memory region lead to exception, you handle it in *VEH* - commit memory and fill with `0xFF` pattern. demo code

```
PVOID g_NandBegin;
SIZE_T g_NandSize = 0x1000000;

LONG NTAPI Vex(::PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo)
{
    ::PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord = ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord;

    if (ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION &&
        ExceptionRecord->NumberParameters > 1)
    {
        PVOID pv = (PVOID)ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1];

        if ((ULONG_PTR)pv - (ULONG_PTR)g_NandBegin < g_NandSize)
        {
            SIZE_T RegionSize = 1;
            if (0 <= NtAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &pv, 0, &RegionSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE))
            {
                RtlFillMemoryUlong(pv, RegionSize, MAXULONG);
                return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
            }
        }
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

void dc()
{
    if (PVOID pv = AddVectoredExceptionHandler(TRUE, Vex))
    {
        if (g_NandBegin = VirtualAlloc(0, g_NandSize, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE))
        {
            ULONG seed = ~GetTickCount();
            int n = 0x100;

            do 
            {
                if (*(UCHAR*)((PBYTE)g_NandBegin + (((ULONG64)RtlRandomEx(&seed) * g_NandSize) >> 32)) != 0xFF)
                {
                    __debugbreak();
                }
            } while (--n);

            VirtualFree(g_NandBegin, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        }
        RemoveVectoredExceptionHandler(pv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you r.e. vectored exception handler..  Tried that and it works well.
Have come up with another slightly different approach - have updated the question.